# How can a SET column be queried in MySQL while ignoring ordering?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL DB with a table that has a `SET` type column with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
col SET('V','A','L','U','E')
)
```

I would like to write a SELECT query that returns all the rows where col equals to ('A','L','E')
This can be done by writing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c = 'A,L,E'
```

The query that i would like to write is one that will return the same result also for an non ordered input like 'L','A','E'

I couldn't find an elegant way to do so and couldn't find anything that can help me in the official documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix nacho's suggestion using the following:

```
WHERE floor(pow(2,FIND_IN_SET('A',c)-1))+
floor(pow(2,FIND_IN_SET('L',c)-1))+
floor(pow(2,FIND_IN_SET('E',c)-1))=c
```

This is by no means an "elegant solution"... I would rather use a simpler one if possible.

FIND_IN_SET provides the position in the enum, so we have to raise 2 by this number to get the internal representation of the SET value.
The floor() function is used to keep the expression 0 when find_in_set returns 0.

Note that you still have the risk of false positives when checking against illegal SET values (e.g. looking for 'A','L','E' and 'X' will return true)

Comment: Thanks, works great, although i was searching for a more elegant solution than this, it seems like MySQL has no better alternative

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FIND IN SET

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('A',c)>0 AND FIND_IN_SET('L',c)>0 AND FIND_IN_SET('E',c)>0
```

I don´t know if this will work but you can also try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('A,L,E',c)>0
```

Comment: The first suggestion checks for containment and not equality. For example i will also get the row that contains 'V,A,L,E' which i don't want.

Comment: The second suggestion is returning empty result set

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to check each item separately + check that the sizes of the groups match (the assumption is that the searched set has no repetitions):

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('A',c)>0 AND FIND_IN_SET('L',c)>0 AND FIND_IN_SET('E',c)>0 AND BIT_COUNT(c) = 3
```